# Is a bug: flag.Parse() could not get values after bool arg?

Tags: go

Why could not get the values that following bool type arg in the command line?
Here's my test code:

```
import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

var stringVal string
var intVal int
var boolValue bool

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&stringVal, "s", "", "string value")
    flag.BoolVar(&boolValue, "b", false, "bool value")
    flag.IntVar(&intVal, "i", -1, "int value")
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Println("stringVal:", stringVal, ", boolValue:", boolValue, ", intVal:", intVal)
}
```

Run it as:

- `go run flag.go -s test -b true -i 10`
  Got: ***stringVal: test , boolValue: true , intVal: -1***
- `go run flag.go -s test -b false -i 10`
  Got: ***stringVal: test , boolValue: true , intVal: -1***
- `go run flag.go -b false -s test -i 10`
  Got: ***stringVal:  , boolValue: true , intVal: -1***
- `go run flag.go -s test -i 10 -b false`
  Got: ***stringVal: test , boolValue: true , intVal: 10***

Go version: 1.16

Comment: on top of the answers provide, `flag.Args()` is also useful to catch any parameters that were not processed - maybe by design, say if arguments are listed after all the flags. This would catch the  invalid `-b false` use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boolean flags are set based on the presence or absence of the flag. They typically default to false, and the presence of the flag is used to modify the default behavior.

For example...

- to display the **long** listing of a directory with `ls`, you use `ls -l`, not `ls -l true`
- to make `rm` safer by having it **interactively** prompt for deletes, you use `rm -i`, not `rm -i true`
- to display human-readable output with `df`, you use `df -h`, not `df -h true`

The `true` and `false` you're placing after the `-b` are being provided to your program as arguments, not as flags, and their presence interrupts further processing of flags.

Add the following to the end of your `main` function:

```
fmt.Println("Remaining args", flag.Args())
```

Given an invocation such as `go run flag.go -b false -s test -i 10`, you'll see that flag processing stopped at `false`, and that the remaining arguments are passed to your program as non-flag arguments:

```
$ go run flag.go -b false -s test -i 10
stringVal:  , boolValue: true , intVal: -1
Remaining args [false -s test -i 10]
```

As an aside, the general philosophy behind "boolean" flags is that you give your program some default behavior, and provide two flags: One which modifies that default, and an opposite flag that negates the modification, restoring the default. When processing flags, the last flag will win.

For example, `rm` provides `-i` to make the command interactive, and `-f` to negate the `-i` flag.

This allows you to set `alias rm="rm -i"` in your shell, meaning all invocations of `rm` will have the `-i` flag applied for safety, prompting you before removing files. However, if you want to run a non-interactive `rm`, you can still type `rm -f`, which expands to be `rm -i -f`, and the last flag (`-f`) wins. Otherwise, you'd have destroy the alias, run `rm` and then restore the alias every time you wanted a non-interactive invocation.

Comment: Thanks. Examples are great. I thought I got it

Answer (score 3):

A boolean flag tests the existence of the flag, not the value of it. If you want to set a value, use:

```
go run flag.go -s test -b=false -i 10
```

Comment: It works. Why not use = for all types? Like `go run flag.go -b=true -s=test -i=11`, also could get the values. Is there any proper reason? Thanks.

Comment: `=` works for all flag types. booleans are the only exception